# How to use kotlin function literals?

Tags: kotlin

So I've got a function literal here:

```
fun task(): List<Boolean> {
    val isEven: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 == 0 }
    val isOdd: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 != 0 }

    return listOf(42.isOdd(), 239.isOdd(), 294823098.isEven())
}
```

and I understand exactly how it's working inside the function - but how is it used outside the function? How is `task()` called? (practical example preferably)

Comment: `val listOfBooleans = task()`?

Comment: To be clear: you have two function literals inside a regular function. The regular function can be called as indicated by @JBNizet. AFAIK, you cannot access the function literals from outside the function.

Comment: You cannot access isEven or isOdd outside of task(). It's called scope.

Comment: If they can't be accessed outside of task(), what is the point? What's a practical use case here?

Comment: your question boils down to "what is the purpose of scoping". The particular element it applies to is not really relevant. If you want to access them outside of task() scope, you define them outside of it.

Comment: "What's a practical use case here?" -> It saves you having to write `42 % 2 != 0`. Instead of that, some people may find `42.isOdd()` a bit more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

When you define function literals inside a function they are available only in the scope of that function:

```
fun task(): List<Boolean> {
    val isEven: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 == 0 } // unavailable outside the `task` function
    val isOdd: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 != 0 }  // unavailable outside the `task` function

    return listOf(42.isOdd(), 239.isOdd(), 294823098.isEven())
}
```

If you want to access those function literals outside the function you need to move them outside the `task` function:

```
val isEven: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 == 0 }
val isOdd: Int.() -> Boolean = { this % 2 != 0 }

fun task(): List<Boolean> {
    return listOf(42.isOdd(), 239.isOdd(), 294823098.isEven())
}

fun anotherTask(): List<Boolean> {
    return listOf(2.isOdd(), 23.isOdd(), 2948.isEven())
}
```

**OR**

Instead of using function literals you can create extension functions:

```
fun Int.isEven(): Boolean { return this % 2 == 0 }
fun Int.isOdd(): Boolean { return this % 2 != 0 }

fun task(): List<Boolean> {
    return listOf(42.isOdd(), 239.isOdd(), 294823098.isEven())
}

fun anotehrTtask(): List<Boolean> {
    return listOf(2.isOdd(), 23.isOdd(), 2948.isEven())
}
```